# Dynamic nginx upstream doesn't work with authorization header

Tags: nginx, http-proxy

I have a problem with a particular nginx setup. The scenario is like this: Applications need to access a couchdb service via a nginx proxy. The nginx needs to set an authorization header in order to get access to the backend. The problem is that the backend service endpoint's DNS changes sometimes and that's causing my services to stop working until I reload nginx.

I'm trying to setup the upstream as a variable, but when I do that, authorization stops working, the backend returns 403. When I just use the upstream directive, it works just fine. The upstream variable has the correct value, no errors in logs.

The config snippet below:

```
set $backend url.to.backend; 

location / { 
  proxy_pass https://$backend/api; 
  proxy_redirect off; 
  proxy_http_version 1.1; 
  proxy_set_header Connection ""; 
  proxy_set_header Host url.to.backend; 
  proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic <authorization_gibberish>"; 
  proxy_temp_path /mnt/nginx_proxy; 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have the commercial version, nginx caches the resolution of an upstream (proxy_pass is basically a "one server upstream"), so the only way to re-resolve it is to perform a restart or reload of the configuration. This is assuming the changing DNS is the issue.

From the [upstream module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) documentation:

> Additionally, the following parameters are available as part of our
>   commercial subscription:

...

> resolve - monitors changes of the IP
>   addresses that correspond to a domain name of the server, and
>   automatically modifies the upstream configuration without the need of
>   restarting nginx (1.5.12)